# How do i get publish date in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress

i want to get post Publish Date like 22 Oct 2014 after the Post title.

i am using `the_title();` for the post title
But how can i get this date ?

Comment: Appears to be asking for just a link to documentation to me. Recommending closure.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [`the_date()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_date) or [`get_the_date()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_date) functions. Either directly:

```
<?php the_date(); ?>
```

or wrap it with `<h2>` tag (for example):

```
<?php get_the_date('F M Y', '<h2>', '</h2>'); ?>
```

Comment: it is working but why i cant not put this in date function & in strtotime

Comment: If you don't want to echo it, you can use `get_the_date()`